# How can I solve the Chrome performance problems on Ubuntu Gnome 15.04?

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, 15.04

I installed Google Chrome on Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 from http://www.google.com/chrome/ , without an existing browser profile in `~/.config`. Syptoms:

- Typing in a form textfield on a web site is stuttering and lagging one second behind the keystroke.
- Clicking a button has a delay of 1 second before the browser shows the click down.

I also installed Chromium from the Ubuntu repositories, same problem. I assume some rendering library is slow or maybe the graphics driver?

```
$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]:
Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 02)
```

Video driver is i915.

Firefox performs normal on this computer with no noticeable delay, so this seems Chrome-specific.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was a bug in Ubuntu 14.10. Chromium was slow in graphics rendring. There is a workaround

Run following command in terminal `sudo xdiagnose` and disable bootloader graphics, VESA framebuffer driver and PAT.

See, If it works for you.
for more information about this bug you can follow this [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1386721)

Comment: **CAUTION**.  This can leave you with a difficult to resolve situation if you disable bootloader graphics.  If you do, see http://askubuntu.com/a/745033/233794 for help to undo this.

Comment: Did not work for me on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

[@Margus Pala](https://askubuntu.com/users/358081/margus-pala) try in chrome going to `chrome://settings` click `show advanced settings...` and uncheck `use hardware acceleration when available`. That worked for me in 16.04